# How to place a progress bar inside TEdit?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

I want to place a progress bar inside TEdit or inside other control like ComboBox.

For example, How to put a progress bar like this ?

[image: progress bar inside control]

I tried with `ProgressBar.Parent := Edit1` is not working.

Comment: You'll want to custom draw this control.

Comment: The Edit controls doesn't support custom draw (via Owner-Drawn) directly, the OP must subclass the control and then handle the WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND  messages.

Comment: @RRUZ What is that if it is not custom draw? Does custom draw have some more specific meaning?

Comment: @David - That is indeed the case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think which you comment means "Owner-Drawn" which is commonly used in Delphi as an alias for custom draw.

Comment: RRUZ, Sertac Thanks for that. I will take more care with my terminology.

Comment: @David - I don't really care much about terminology. In any case if we are to use MS terminology, 'owner-drawn' refers the drawing process by means of `WM_DRAWITEM` while 'custom draw' refers the same by means of `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`.

Comment: Now I tested to see how it fails. It doesn't. A progressbar is parented by an Edit just fine by setting the Parent property. You may want to explain *"not working"*. Do you want to see the edit text for instance?

Comment: Yes, what @Sertac said.  Remember, "it doesn't work" are the least useful words in the history of error reporting.  Much more helpful would be explaining *what you wanted to have happen* and *what happened instead*.

Comment: Can't you make the editbox partially transparent? And show a progressbar underneigh?